# Style pane shows many instances of a style, but I can't find, change, or delete the style

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles

I converted a file from Word 97-2003 compatible to Word 2010.

The style pane shows a style that is attached to many instances of text. In this case, the style is a "re-styling" from Normal to 11 pt, Centered, Line spacing: single!

But I can't clear it, delete it, or change it, or find what the style is attached to.

I tried creating a new style from it, changing the name to Ditch-Me (thinking all it needed was a little "shake up" so that I could go on a search and destroy mission). That did not work.

So then I tried making an outrageous change to it (16 point red text), thinking I could scroll through text and find it that way. The change is apparent while in the Modify Style box, but the change won't stick.

Here's a screenshot of the problem. Presumably the style is hidden in all or part of the text you see in the background. Notice that in the Modify box, the text is changed to big red, centered. But I click ok and nothing happens.

[image: Cannot delete style]

Note: The file actually has multiple, similarly "troubled" styles. Hopefully there is one solution I can use to delete the other styles as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When faced with the mystery of that-which-will-not-delete, here are three things that have worked for me alone or in combination:

- Select the errant text and press Ctrol + spacebar to remove formatting and revert to plain text.
- Methodically find and either ditch or create new styles from styles that show as Style + direct formatting. For example, if you see custom-title-text + magenta, then either ditch it or rename it to custom-title-text-magenta.
- Run a macro for [DeleteUnusedStyles](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008522_Unwanted_Styles.html)